# Extending class dynamically in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, modx, user-defined-literals

I need to extend class dynamically and use this code:

```
Calc.grid.Table["Table"+key] = function(config) {
        config = config || {};
        Ext.applyIf(config,{
                id: 'calc-grid-table'+key
                ,baseParams: { 
                    action: 'mgr/calc/calcGetTable'+key
                    ,query: 'Calc'+key 
                }
        });
        Calc.grid.Table["Table"+key].superclass.constructor.call(this,config)
};
Ext.extend(Calc.grid.Table["Table"+key],Calc.grid.Table);
Ext.reg('calc-grid-table'+key,Calc.grid.Table["Table"+key]);
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'superclass' of undefined
```

I tried to change it to this

```
this.superclass.constructor.call(this,config)
```

but error is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The problem is in dynamic literals. When I do like this it works fine

```
Calc.grid.Table.Table21 = function(config) {
        config = config || {};
        Ext.applyIf(config,{
                id: 'calc-grid-table'+21
                ,baseParams: { 
                    action: 'mgr/calc/calcGetTable'+21
                    ,query: 'Calc'+21
                }
        });
        Calc.grid.Table.Table21.superclass.constructor.call(this,config)
};
Ext.extend(Calc.grid.Table.Table21,Calc.grid.Table);
Ext.reg('calc-grid-table'+21,Calc.grid.Table.Table21);
```

How can I fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Most likely `key` changes before the constructor is called. Can you show some more code?

Comment: @Pumbaa80, Thank you so much! That was a problem. key was iterating in a loop. Now I have new exeption "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'stopEditing' of undefined". Do you have any idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You're `key` variable being used in your constructor isn't scoped to that function, so it is possible that is can be changed before the constructor is called.  You can use Ext's `createDelegate` to tie the variable to the function so that it can't change on you:

```
Calc.grid.Table["Table"+key] = function(key, config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config,{
            id: 'calc-grid-table'+key
            ,baseParams: { 
                action: 'mgr/calc/calcGetTable'+key
                ,query: 'Calc'+key 
            }
    });
    Calc.grid.Table["Table"+key].superclass.constructor.call(this,config)
}.createDelegate(this, [key], 0);
```